# Optimising mongo query in a 4 millions row collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo collection which has 4 millions rows.
I have to get informations from it when loading a page, but the request takes a lot of time.

I'm using the mongodb module in nodeJs
My request looks like this :

```
collection.findOne(userId: "id1", videoId: "id2")
```

I found out that when I use _id instead of userId and videoId like this

```
collection.findOne(_id: "id1")
```

The query becomes much faster. Thing is, I cannot use the _id the first time I get on the page. Right now the page takes 3 to 5 seconds to load, and I would like to make it take less time, like 1-2 seconds max.
I was thinking maybe I should preload all the user information somewhere when he comes on the site, so I don't have to query on the big collection when I get to that specific page.

But i was wondering is there anyway i can make the query faster ?

Comment: Use better [indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/)?

Comment: you can follow the documentation by MongoDB [Optimize Query Performance](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, i'm struggling a little bit to understand how the indexes work but i'll try